# Try to add elements to recyclerview (ConcurrentModificationException)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, addition

I'm trying to add items to the list, but there is an error, I can not figure out how to solve it. 
Here is an example of adding:

```
for (Object object : mData) {
    if (object instanceof BaseAdapter.ChoseFriendItem) {
               mAdapter.addItem(1, object);
    }
}
```

where the mDate - arraylist 
After executing the code I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.akbars.bankok, PID: 15263    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
at com.akbars.bankok.v2.ActivityChoseFriends.onClick(ActivityChoseFriends.java:311)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Then I tried to use an iterator. But why is it only adds one element and not from the beginning of the list, here's an example:

```
for (ListIterator<Object> iterator = mData.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     if (iterator.next() instanceof BaseAdapter.ChoseFriendItem){
         mAdapter.addItem(1, iterator.next());
         return;
     }
}
```

Maybe somebody knows how to fix this error?

Comment: Why do you add items always to the second (1) position?

Answer (score 2):

This code your code should be something like this :

```
for (ListIterator<Object> iterator = mData.listIterator(); iterator
                                .hasNext();) {
                            Object item = iterator.next();
                            if (item instanceof BaseAdapter.ChoseFriendItem){
                                mAdapter.addItem(1, item);
                                //return; There should be no return statement here.
                            }
                        }
```

> You called iterator.next() two times which will one element each time and give incorrect results.

Comment: it does not work for my case, the error appears on this line: Object item = iterator.next();

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and i my case i took server response list:

```
localList = serverResponseList;
```

and when i tried to add new elements (localList.addAll(ListWithNewElements)) receive same error.

To avoid this error you simply need create new list, and then add to new created list your elements:

```
public ListAdapter(List<> itemCollections) {
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.itemCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    this.itemCollection.addAll(itemCollection);
}


public void addBarsCollection(List<Bar> itemCollection) {
    this.itemCollection.addAll(itemCollection);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can assume it is because you are adding elements only to the first index of the items in the adapter.

```
mAdapter.addItem(1, item);
```

Increase the first argument by 1 each time you want to add a new item to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you are doing here:

```
for (ListIterator<Object> iterator = mData.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     if (iterator.next() instanceof BaseAdapter.ChoseFriendItem){
         mAdapter.addItem(1, iterator.next());
         return;
     }
}
```

You add every next item to the second position. Why?

Solution adds one after another beginning with position 0 ("informatic count"):

```
while(iterator.hasNext())mAdapter.addItem(iterator.next());
```

If this does not work and I could not imagine why it should not try this:

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();
                final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       mAdapter.addItem(iterator.next())
                    }
                };

  handler.post(r);
```